# Ignoring data under a specific section in a string using Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I have a string as shown  below

```
line="record of Students Name Codes:  AC1.123  XYZ12.67  the student is math major first hisory: XY12.34 good performer second history M12.78 N23.76 faculty Miss Cooper"
```

I want to extract some codes from the line. I am using the below program for that. I want to ignore codes which are in history sections.

May I know how to ignore the codes from the sections which have history in them

```
import re
regular_expression = re.compile(r'\b[A-Z]+\d{1,2}\.*\d{1,2}\w{0,2}\b', re.I)
matches = regular_expression.findall(line)
for match in matches:
    print (match)
```

Expected Output

```
AC1.123
XYZ12.67
```

Currrent Output:

```
AC1.123
XYZ12.67
XY12.34
M12.78
N23.76
```

Comment: How do you define a block here? Why not first split into blocks?

Comment: ya that's what I am thinking that how to define the block here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match all the values from the history that you don't want, followed by capturing in a group what you do want:

```
\bhistory:? [A-Z]+\d+\.\d+(?: [A-Z]+\d+\.\d+)*|([A-Z]+\d+\.\d+(?: [A-Z]+\d+)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `\bhistory:?` Word boundary, match history, optional colon and space
- `[A-Z]+\d+\.\d+` Match 1+ times a-z, 1+ digits, dot literal and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[A-Z]+\d+\.\d+` Repeat matching previous pattern with a space prepended
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `|` or
- `(` Capturing group

  - `[A-Z]+\d+\.\d+` Match same as first pattern
  - `(?: [A-Z]+\d+)*` Repeat same pattern with a space prepended
- `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJKYTc/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YC18yu)

I assumed that `hisory` is a typo that should be `history`

For example:

```
import re
line = "record of Students Name Codes:  AC1.123  XYZ12.67  the student is math major first history: XY12.34 good performer second history M12.78 N23.76 faculty Miss Cooper"
regular_expression = re.compile(r'\bhistory:? [A-Z]+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?: [A-Z]+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)*|([A-Z]+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(?: [A-Z]+[0-9]+)*)', re.I)
matches = regular_expression.findall(line)
print(list(filter(None, matches)))
```

Result

> ['AC1.123', 'XYZ12.67']

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what might be your desired rules, however this might help you to design [an expression](https://regex101.com/r/OFDWVB/1/):

```
(AC|XYZ)([0-9]+.[0-9]+)
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how an expression like that would work:

[image]

#### Example Test

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re

string = "record of Students Name Codes:  AC1.123  XYZ12.67  the student is math major first hisory: XY12.34 good performer second history M12.78 N23.76 faculty Miss Cooper"
expression = r'((AC|XYZ)([0-9]+.[0-9]+))'
match = re.search(expression, string)
if match:
    print("YAAAY! \"" + match.group(1) + "\" is a match  ")
else: 
    print(' Sorry! No matches! Something is not right! Call 911 ')
```

Comment: the code is not strict to AC or XYZ. It could be anything